# SQL Return rows by highest date

Tags: sql-server

I'm having issues getting rows by max date with product quantity

Here is the Products table

```
SupplierCode    Reference   Qty
1000            M131200     500
1111            M131200     1
1000            M131300     200
1111            M131300     500
```

and here is the Orders table

```
SupplierCode    Reference   OrderDate
1000            M131200     2019-01-09 00:00:00.000
1111            M131200     2018-07-25 00:00:00.000
1000            M131200     2019-01-15 00:00:00.000
1000            M131200     2019-01-21 00:00:00.000
1111            M131200     2019-01-02 00:00:00.000
1111            M131300     2019-02-05 00:00:00.000
1000            M131300     2019-03-05 00:00:00.000
1000            M131300     2019-04-07 00:00:00.000
1111            M131300     2019-02-04 00:00:00.000
```

All I need is to return product quantity per Reference so I can join to another table. The problem is that there's more than one supplier, so references will make duplicate results on my final query because one reference can have more than one supplier.

I managed to get the latest date for each supplier

```
SELECT
    O.SupplierCode,
    O.Reference,
    MAX(OrderDate) AS Date
FROM 
    Orders O
GROUP BY 
    O.SupplierCode,
    O.Reference
```

which returns this

```
SupplierCode    Reference   Date
1000            M131200     2019-01-21 00:00:00.000
1111            M131200     2019-01-02 00:00:00.000
1000            M131300     2019-04-07 00:00:00.000
1111            M131300     2019-02-05 00:00:00.000
```

So now I need to pick the supplier with the latest date for each reference

For example, the final output I'm looking for is this, of course this is faster having joined both tables:

```
SupplierCode    Reference   Qty Date
1000            M131200     500 2019-01-21 00:00:00.000
1000            M131300     200 2019-04-07 00:00:00.000
```

But I'm not sure how I should make this date verification on `where` clause

Comment: This has been asked and answered hundreds and hundreds of times. Search for "top N per group". Hint, you use ROW_NUMBER

Comment: I knew about top 1 but i thought it just returned one row, but not about top N per group

Comment: I don't mean using TOP. I mean using ROW_NUMBER to return the top N per group. In your case the group is SupplierCode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pick the latest supplier per Reference using ROW_NUMBER():

```
with maxOrder as 
(
    select
        *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Reference ORDER BY OrderDate DESC) as number
    from Orders
)
Select
     o.SupplierCode
    ,o.Reference
    ,p.Qty
    ,o.OrderDate
from maxOrder as o
join Products as p
    on p.SupplierCode = o.SupplierCode
    and p.Reference = o.Reference
where o.number = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, I had used partition only once and i didn't know i could use this right now. Really changes everything. Also is there any performance issues using partition?

Comment: If you want to delve into window functions (they are great!) I strongly recommend you to read this artcile -> https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/how-use-microsoft-sql-server-2012s-window-functions-part-1 Itzik Ben- Gan has also an awesome book on this topic. Usually, performance is good using window functions.